# Best Practice: Using Id or Name in Filter Criteria and Formula Fields

Tags: formula, salesforce-id, bestpractice, filters

We're working in an Org that uses Ids in Filter Criteria and Formula Fields to dictate logic based on Record Types. When you refresh a sandbox, it maps the correct Id to the correct record type id and it seems like it does some global find and replace on almost all Id mentions which is great.

One problem is when you have to look at the filter criteria or formula field, an Id doesn't really tell you anything without running a SOQL query for the record type or plugging the Id in the url.

The other problem is on non-change set deployments like say Custom Metadata records where you have to look up the Id of the record to set it in a field and then do it again after you test and promote the change.

If there is a Salesforce preferred method, what is it? To use the Id or to use Name/DeveloperName on a separate field?

Comment: Salesforce generally recommends against hard-coding Ids. And I think a good number of consultants would agree that the readability of using names is a huge boon. I would highly recommend using them over ids.

Comment: You can almost always check for RecordType.DeveloperName (I prefer DeveloperName to Name, because in the event the label needs to change for clarity we don't have to update all references). The one exception is in a trigger, where you can compare against the Id by the developer name like this Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Standard').getRecordTypeId()